# Get all Wikipedia Infobox Templates and all Pages using them

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, sparql, dbpedia

Given a Wikipedia page like [Wikipedia: Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) there are often Infoboxes (mostly on the right hand at the top of the page). Example screenshot:

[image: Stackoverflow Infobox at Wikipedia]

1. DBPedia lists all these attributes as RDF triples. You can see the example at [DBPedia: Stack Overflow](http://dbpedia.org/page/Stack_Overflow). There you see the property `dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate` with the value `dbpedia:Template:Infobox_website` which is interesting. I want to know which Wikipedia pages use this template. How can i do that and list all pages which use the Infobox_website template? Preferably with a SPARQL query but i am open to other easy solutions.
2. Next thing is a list of all Infobox Templates. [Wikipedia: Category Infobox Templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Infobox_templates) shows the hierarchy of the desired Wikipedia categories - that looks like what i am seeking. But i want all of these in a machine readable format, on one page. Maybe DBPedia is the right thing here too? At [DBPedia: Category Infox Templates](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Infobox_templates) and [DBPedia: INFOBOX](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:INFOBOX) i find very few information. But these are looking very promising. How can i use SPARQL to find all Infobox Types so that i can do step 1 repeatedly for each of them?

You can use this for testing the SPARQL queries: http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

### Update 1

I seem to have solved problem number 1: [SPARQL: list all pages with Infobox_website](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20?page%20dbpedia2:wikiPageUsesTemplate%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_website%3E%20.%20%20?page%20dbpedia2:name%20?name%20.%7D)

### Update 2

Also, this seems to be the query for problem number 2: [SPARQL: list all Infoboxes](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?template%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?page%20dbpedia2:wikiPageUsesTemplate%20?template%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28regex%28?template,%20%22Infobox%22%29%29%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20?template%0D%0A)

Comment: Your "Update 1" query now returns no results. Do you have a working solution still?

Comment: sorry, i am stuck too. please let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Yeah found a solution, will add as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answers seem to have stopped working. Only a small change is required to get them working at the new dbpedia query endpoint at http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql though.

To get a list of all of the pages and the templates that they use this query works:

```
SELECT * WHERE {  ?page  dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate ?template . }
```

[See results (limited to 100)](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%20?page%20dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate%20?template%20.%20%7D%20LIMIT%20100)

If you're looking for a specific template:

```
SELECT * WHERE {  
   ?page  
   dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate 
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_website> . 
}
```

[See results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%20?page%20dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_website%3E%20.%20%7D)

And for my use case I'm interested in the Wikipedia URL rather than the DBPedia page, so I'm using this query:

```
SELECT ?wikipedia_url WHERE {  
   ?page  
   dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate 
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_website> . 
   ?page foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipedia_url .
}
```

[See results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20?wikipedia_url%20WHERE%20%7B%20?page%20dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_website%3E%20.%20?page%20foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf%20?wikipedia_url%20.%20%7D)

I'm also using `curl` to pull the results into a script:

```
$ curl -s "http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fwikipedia_url+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A%09+%3Fpage+%0D%0A%09+dbpprop%3AwikiPageUsesTemplate+%0D%0A%09+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FTemplate%3AInfobox_website%3E+.+%0D%0A+%3Fpage+foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf+%3Fwikipedia_url+.%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%7D&format=text%2Ftab-separated-values" \
| tr -d \" | grep -v "^wikipedia_url$" | head
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._News_&_World_Report
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FriendFinder
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debkafile
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTPlanet
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_Wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connexions
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypno5ive
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoop_(website)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhoomi_(software)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainwashed_(website)
```

I'm not sure if this gives the full result set though, because it returns 1698 results whereas [wmflabs.org](https://tools.wmflabs.org/templatecount/index.php?lang=en&namespace=10&name=Infobox%20website#bottom) seems to suggest there should be 4439.

---

For the second part of your question, only a small change is needed from the previous query to get a list of all templates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?template WHERE { 
    ?page  
    dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate  
    ?template . 
    FILTER (regex(?template, "Infobox")) . 
} ORDER BY ?template
```

[See results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Ftemplate%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fpage%20%20dbpprop%3AwikiPageUsesTemplate%20%20%3Ftemplate%20.%20FILTER%20%28regex%28%3Ftemplate%2C%20%22Infobox%22%29%29%20.%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Ftemplate&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you add SPARQL links to the new endpoint with the solution to both problems in the question, i'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: The new endpoint doesn't let you link directly to the query browser. I will add links to the results though.

Comment: Oh, let me also answer the second part

Comment: the `dbpprop` prefix generates a `Undefined namespace prefix` error, replacing it by `dbp` seems to do the trick

Answer (score 8):

Ok, since i seem to have found a solution (most probably not the best) i want to share them.

1) This SPARQL query can be used to find all pages that include a specific Infobox type:

> SELECT * WHERE {   ?page dbpedia2:wikiPageUsesTemplate
>   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_website> .   ?page
>   dbpedia2:name ?name . }

[Link at SNORQL](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20?page%20dbpedia2%3awikiPageUsesTemplate%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Template%3aInfobox_website%3E%20.%20%20?page%20dbpedia2%3aname%20?name%20.%7D)

---

2) This SPARQL query can be used to find all Infobox types:

> SELECT DISTINCT ?template WHERE {   ?page
>   dbpedia2:wikiPageUsesTemplate ?template .    FILTER (regex(?template,
>   "Infobox")) . } ORDER BY ?template

[Link at SNORQL](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?template%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?page%20dbpedia2%3awikiPageUsesTemplate%20?template%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28regex%28?template,%20%22Infobox%22%29%29%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20?template%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the MediaWiki API's [embeddedin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aEmbeddedin) query to return a list of all pages that include a given template.  You'll want to use a library for accessing the API though, which language would you prefer?  For Ruby, I'd suggest [MediaWiki::Gateway](https://github.com/jpatokal/mediawiki-gateway).

Comment: these look very limited. how to display all types of infoboxes at once?